# Find Characters Stripost From Database Using Loop If, Elseif and Else

Tags: php, arrays, loops, stripos

I have the following code:

```
for ($y = 0; $y <= $count_1; $y++) {
    for ($x = 0; $x <= $count_2; $x++) {
        if((strpos($cat[$y],"Model 1")!==false)and (stripos($quest[$y],$search_quest[$x])!==false) and (stripos($answ[$y],$search_answ[$x])!== false)) { 
            $ai_cat_detail ="FOUND";
        } else {
            $ai_cat_detail ="N/A";
        }
    }
    echo $ai_cat_detail."<br>";
}
```

Result Is:

N/A
N/A
N/A
N/A
N/A

I am expected value like this:
Found
Found
Found
N/A
N/A

And success with this code:

```
if((strpos($cat[$y],"Model 1")!==false)and(stripos($quest[$y],"Search Quest 1")!==false) and (stripos($answ[$y],"Search Answer 1")!== false)) {     
    $ai_cat_detail = "FOUND";
} elseif((strpos($cat[$y],"Model 1")!==false)and(stripos($quest[$y],"Search Quest 2")!==false) and (stripos($answ[$y],"Search Answer 2")!== false)){ 
    $ai_cat_detail = "FOUND";
} elseif((strpos($cat[$y],"Model 1")!==false)and (stripos($quest[$y],"Search Quest 3")!==false) and (stripos($answ[$y],"Search Answer 3")!== false)) { 
    $ai_cat_detail = "FOUND";
} elseif((strpos($cat[$y],"Model 1")!==false)and (stripos($quest[$y],"Search Quest 4")!==false) and (stripos($answ[$y],"Search Answer 4")!== false)) { 
    $ai_cat_detail = "FOUND";
} else { 
    $ai_cat_detail = "N/A";
}
```

So whats can i do to loop a else if and end with code else like my success code above?

Thanks for help

Comment: Because strpos return integer type value and here you check with Boolean type.(!== means it will check value as well as type.)So all time it will return false.

Comment: Instead of using false with comparison use integer values to compare. For more reference visit.... http://php.net/manual/en/function.strpos.php

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You having the wrong output as you overwrite the value of `$ai_cat_detail` in your loop - so the last assign is `N/A` is the one you echo (so it will echo `FOUND` only if the last if was found.

In order to fix that export the check to function and return the string value or use **break** as:

```
for ($y = 0; $y <= $count_1; $y++) {
    for ($x = 0; $x <= $count_2; $x++) {
        if((strpos($cat[$y],"Model 1") !== false) and (stripos($quest[$y],$search_quest[$x]) !== false) and (stripos($answ[$y],$search_answ[$x]) !== false)) { 
            $ai_cat_detail ="FOUND";
            break; // this will stop the loop if founded
        } else {
            $ai_cat_detail ="N/A";
        }
    }
    echo $ai_cat_detail."<br>";
}
```

Or use function as:

```
function existIn($cat, $search_quest, $search_answ, $count_2, $y) {
    for ($x = 0; $x <= $count_2; $x++) {
        if((strpos($cat[$y],"Model 1") !== false) and (stripos($quest[$y],$search_quest[$x]) !== false) and (stripos($answ[$y],$search_answ[$x]) !== false)) { 
            return "FOUND";
        }
    }
    return "N/A";

//use as
for ($y = 0; $y <= $count_1; $y++) {
    echo existIn($cat, $search_quest, $search_answ, $count_2, $y) ."<br>";
}
```